# PySimpleGUI apply function to dataframe input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-interface, input

Hello i want to ask some questions:

- How can i give a dataframe as input in my GUI
- How can i apply a function to the dataframe which is the input

So i was building a standard GUI code to read input looking like this:

```
layout = [[sg.Text('Add your Excel-Dataframe here:', sg.Input(key = '-IN-']
          [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Exit')]
         ]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
while True: 
event, values = window.read()
if event is None or event == 'Exit':
    break
window ['-OUT-'].update('-IN-')


window.close()
```

So i want the input to be an excel-dataframe where i want to apply several methods

Can someone help me pls?